# Insertion in a singly linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

What are the pros and cons of the following approaches for insertion in a singly linked list?

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void insert(struct node** head,int val)
{
    struct node *nptr=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    nptr->data=val;
    nptr->next=*head;
    *head=nptr;
}

struct node* insert(struct node *head,int val)
{
    struct node *nptr=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    nptr->data=val;
    nptr->next=head;
    return nptr;
}
```

Comment: Asking for feedback on existing working code belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

A function, which returns `node*`, can be used in expressions. For example, in order to create a list with 2 nodes you can write (in theory):

```
node* head = insert(insert(NULL, 1), 2);
```

However, in *real life* you have to check the return value of the `malloc`. It means, that both functions need to be modified to include this check. For example, a more correct version of the first function would be:

```
bool insert(struct node** head,int val)
{
  struct node *nptr=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if (nptr != NULL)
  {
    nptr->data=val;
    nptr->next=*head;
    *head=nptr;
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Using these modified functions in expressions will still be possible, but you'll have to call them via [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C), which will add length and complexity to the expression.

As for calling efficiency for both your cases there is no definite answer as well. Your code might be compiled by various compilers for various hardware - for example, see [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) to better understand what is going on between caller function and callee one. So, in some cases the first function will be a little bit faster, and in some other cases the second one. And - some compilers will even compile both your functions into the exactly same Assembly code.

Comment: your point is right. But i don't this this is the intention of the question.
@anjaneypandey has given two way to insert in linked list, and asking, which is better and efficient way and why?